# resize_images with a batch

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, resize

I'm trying to read three jpg-Files to resize them with a tensorflow batch. No matter what I tried I didn't succeed. Here is one example below. In general how can I resize some pictures in a batch with tf.image.resize_images. I don't want to use an Input Reader. I want to create the batch of some pictures by myself.

I think it's neccessary to have 4 dimensions like batchsize, width, heigt, channels

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

tensor_list = []

for i in range(3):
    img = tf.read_file("{0}.jpg".format(i))
    img_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, 3)
    img_resized = tf.image.resize_images(img_tensor, tf.convert_to_tensor([ 800, 400 ] ), tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
    img_tensor_dim = tf.expand_dims(img_resized, 0)
    tensor_list.append(img_tensor_dim)

batch = tf.train.batch(tensor_list, batch_size=3, enqueue_many=False)

img_resized = tf.image.resize_images(batch, tf.convert_to_tensor([400, 200]), tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)

for i in range(3):
    tmp = img_resized[i] 
    endcode_jpg = tf.image.encode_jpeg(tmp, x_density=96, y_density=96)
    wr = tf.write_file('{0}_out.jpg'.format(i), endcode_jpg)
    sess.run(wr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) operation to apply the resizing logic to a vector of strings containing your image data:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Build a tensor containing the image data as a vector of strings.
images = []
for i in range(3):
  images.append(tf.read_file("/tmp/jpeg420exif.jpg"))
images = tf.stack(images)

# `resize_fn()` contains the logic for resizing and encoding one image.
def resize_fn(img):
  img_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, 3)
  img_resized = tf.image.resize_images(
      [img_tensor], [800, 400], tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)[0]
  img_encoded = tf.image.encode_jpeg(img_resized, x_density=96, y_density=96)
  return img_encoded

# `tf.map_fn()` applies `resize_fn()` to each image in turn, and
# returns a vector of encoded images.
encoded_images = tf.map_fn(resize_fn, images)

write_ops = []
for i in range(3):
  write_ops.append(tf.write_file("{0}_out.jpg".format(i), encoded_images[i]))

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(write_ops)
```

Comment: Thank your for this solution. But actually I want to use the resize_images function with a batch, see first argument of resize_images

 images: 4-D Tensor of shape [batch, height, width, channels] or 3-D Tensor    of shape [height, width, channels].

So how can I create a batch in form of a 4-D Tensor?

Generelly I have some 3-D Tensors with height, width and channels. How can I summarized them in a 4-D Tensor for example

[first image, height, width, channels]
[second image, heigth, widht, channels]
[third image, heigth, widht, channels]

Comment: The `tf.image.resize_images()` function only works on a batch if all of the images in the batch have the same `[height, width, channels]` shape. If they are, you can simply stack them with `tf.stack()` and pass them to `tf.image.resize_images()`. If not, you'll need to use something like the approach in my answer to perform the decoding and resizing separately on each image.